# halting after errors happen in catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, throw

I recently read about it is a good practice to write `throw error` when an error appears in order to stop dealing with the errant results. I am not sure if whether it applies to the server of a web app built with node.js and express. Should I handle all the `.catch` with `throw error.` Would `throw error` causes my app to crash?

Comment: Your question is a little to broad. The answer here is "it depends". If the error is fatal (meaning that your app cannot function correctly), for example if it does not have correct DB credentials, then yes, maybe it's better for it to crash, and setup monitoring/alerting when your app keeps crashing and restarting. If, however, the error is just that some user posted data in a format you cannot use, then it's good to throw, so that you get some logs, but you should handle (catch) that error, and not make it crash your whole app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch block is where you handle the error. In other words, this is where you could potentially trigger an alternate result from the function. Example:

```
try {
  const result = await fetchSomeData();
  if(result !== null) {  
    return result;
  }else{
    throw "nothing was fetched"
  }
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
  const result = { error: "a custom error message", function: customCallBack };
  return result;
}
```

Comment: in that case, do I need to have the `throw` inside my `catch` instead of just `console.log` it

Comment: No, throw is for creating an exception (error), and catch is for catching (handling) the error. In this example, the fetch didn't return an error, it returned null, which would likely cause an error somewhere else in the application. So, instead of waiting for it to cause an error somewhere else, I'm controlling it by throwing an error, then handling the error in the catch block by logging it and then creating an alternate result that the application can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Catching your errors properly is a good habit in every language (which supports it, of course). This applies for every code you write, no matter if it is some server, client or anything else.

The whole point of catching an error is to avoid your app from crashing without noticing and handle the reason for crashing appropriately, for example, inform user (or yourself) that there was some problem, stop processing some loop, stop the whole application or whatever else makes sense for your case.